# Find FK in table using Lambda/LINQ and using a WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, lambda

I'm trying to find a value in my database.
Using my WPF project, my MVVM has a view that displays a value that is in the table, call it Child.

How do I, using Lambda or LINQ, get the Name of a child from the table where the FK, being Teacher is equals to the Teacher in Teacher table?

Lets just remove the whole MVVM and WPF out of this. I'm learning to use Lambda, and LINQ is rusty to me. But the project I'm helping out with uses loads of Lambda, so I must stick to protocol.

Hopefully this makes sense to someone. All I want is a value out the table by checking a given value

In SQL, we would go

```
select Name from Child where Child.TID = 1
```

where TID is the Teacher ID and the foreign key for Child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this :

```
var childNames = (from c in DataContext.Child where c.TID == 1 select c.Name).ToList();
```

or using method syntax :

```
var childNames = DataContext.Child.Where(o => o.TID == 1).Select(o => o.Name).ToList();
```